# ST_SymDifference with dblink

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to create a table (table_diff) that is a result of symmetrical difference (ST_SymDifference) between geometries (linestrings) from 2 tables (table1, table2) stored in 2 databases (db1, db2).

So far I have a command that works on 2 tables that are in the same database:

```
psql -U postgres -d db1 -c "CREATE TABLE table_diff AS SELECT ST_SymDifference(ST_Union(DISTINCT table1.geom),ST_Union(DISTINCT table2.geom)) AS geom FROM public.table1, public.table2
```

Below is my effort in trying to implement dblink to access table2 from db2 which doesn't work and which I need help with.

```
psql -U postgres -d db1 -c "CREATE TABLE table_diff AS SELECT ST_SymDifference(ST_Union(DISTINCT table1.geom),ST_Union(DISTINCT dblink('dbname=db2', 'SELECT geom FROM public.table2'))) AS geom FROM public.table1, dblink('dbname=db', 'SELECT geom FROM public.table2')"
```

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

Comment: Usually with dblink, you need an explict AS (col1, col2.....) after the query, which I suspect is what the error means. You might want to use postgres_fdw instead, as it is a lot less painful to deal with. I don't know how large your tables are, but neither dblink nor postgres_fdw will use indexes on a non-native Postgres type (ie, no spatial indexes), so this query is likely to be somewhat slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dblink` function returns a dynamic `SETOF RECORD`, thus you will need to declare each return column in an alias list.

**Updated:**

You will also need to union both table's geometries separately to execute the final cross join, e.g. via CTE; assuming you are logged into `db1`, you can run

```
WITH
  t1 AS (
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
    FROM public.table1
  ),

  t2 AS (
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom
    FROM dblink('<connstring_db2>', 'SELECT geom FROM table2') AS t(geom GEOMETRY)
  )

CREATE TABLE table_diff AS
    SELECT ST_SymDifference(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS geom
    FROM t1,
         t2;
```

---

You might want to consider using [*postgres_fdw*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) as @JohnPowell suggested.

Comment: OP, actually has two dblink statements, not that this undermines your answer in any way.

Comment: @JohnPowell hm yes, but I deemed that unnecessary...or actually wrong. but I might be wrong here!?

Comment: No, I think you need two separate statements -- I could be wrong. I have always found dblink somewhat painful. I believe this would be much better handled with postgres_fdw syntax, which feels more natural, two CTE tables to fetch results, and then a final query to do the difference.

Comment: @JohnPowell I will check...for now I updated the query with a generic `dbname=<external_db>`

Comment: @JohnPowell so, yes and no; I didn´t really realize the `ST_Union` construct and changed my query accordingly now (also with CTE's for simplicity), but in general you wouldn´t need a second dblink if you only want to get *one* table from *one* foreign DB, since you should naturally be logged into the working DB already...

Comment: yes, sure, it wasn't totally clear from the question, but obviously, as you have written it, you could easily extend to two db_link statements. My guess is that the perfomance of this query will be horrible, but that is a different matter, and not easily fixed with remote servers.

Comment: @JohnPowell okay...done then, everybody wins ,) ...or did everybody? Still not sure if this is what was intended....

Comment: no idea, but we had a nice chat on a Friday afternoon :D.

Comment: JohnPowell and @ThingumaBob thank you for your help - this is exactly what I wanted. :) As suggested, I have also switched to postgres_fdw - faster and easier to use. Thank you!